# IUPAC Nomenclature of Benzene+Aliphatic chain

Tags: nomenclature

[image: molecule]

What is this compound's IUPAC name?

1) [2-phenyloctane](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2-phenyloctane&x=0&y=0).
2) [octan-2-ylbenzene](http://www.chemicalize.org/structure/#!mol=2-phenyloctane).

Is using phenyl correct or is taking benzene as the base correct?

Comment: I did the following searches to find that if aliphatic chain has more than 6 carbon atoms then it prefers using phenyl : http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2-phenylpentane&x=0&y=0   &   http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2-phenylhexane&x=0&y=0 . Also [this](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Hydrocarbons/Aromatics/Nomenclature_of_Benzenes#The_Phenyl_Group) says so too. So is it correct ?

Comment: I cant add more than 2 links , hence the comments . Can someone add it in the question ?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎ Let me get this straight: You can't add links?! And, [tag:iupac] is used for the IUPAC org itself, not nomenclature.

Comment: @Loong So both of them are correct ?

Comment: @MARamezani Not more than two links

Comment: @pikachu Yes, both ‘octan-2-ylbenzene’ and ‘2-phenyloctane’ are correct; ‘octan-2-ylbenzene’ is the preferred IUPAC name.

Comment: @Loong But [this](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Hydrocarbons/Aromatics/Nomenclature_of_Benzenes#The_Phenyl_Group) says _While compounds like these are usually named by simple benzene type naming (chlorobenzene and bromobenzene), the phenyl group naming is usually applied to benzene rings where a substituent with six or more carbons is attached, such as in the diagram below._

Comment: @Loong Please have a look at my previous comment . thanks.

Comment: @pikachu That site is not necessarily wrong, since according to current IUPAC recommendations (2013), “the context _may_ favor (…) the chain, so that (…) an unsaturated acyclic structure may be recognized, or the one chosen has the greater number of skeletal atoms (…) in the principal chain of the acyclic structure.” However, the approach for the _preferred IUPAC name_ (PIN) prefers the choice of a ring over a chain in systems composed of cyclic and acyclic hydrocarbons.

Comment: @pikachu The old IUPAC rule (from 1979) actually was: “Choice between these methods is made according to the more appropriate of the following principles: (…) (b) treatment of a smaller of structure as a substituent into a larger. (…) In accordance with the principle (b) (…), a hydrocarbon containing a small cyclic nucleus attached to a long chain is generally named as a derivative of the acyclic hydrocarbon; (…)”

Comment: @Loong Okay . Thanks !!! So the site goes with the 1979 rule .